# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

receiving the following error session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76

Using latest webdrivermanager version 3.6.2

Seems like it is not finding the latest version of chrome on my machine Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit).

code is below, failure is occuring on return statement

```
WebDriver getDriver() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");

        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'QJ07301311', ip: '10.58.72.245', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: Driver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF7C93+1473683]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7ADB1+961969]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F042E3+475875]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E9F365+62309]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E9BC77+48247]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB9149+168265]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB8D1D+167197]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB742B+160811]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA0AE6+68326]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA1BF0+72688]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA1B89+72585]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F94B77+1067895]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01096875+506677]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01096610+506064]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0109D1B8+533624]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0109704A+508682]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8C266+1032806]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8C0DF+1032415]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F96A8B+1075851]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F96BF3+1076211]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F95BA5+1072037]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x757F343D+18]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77DA9802+99]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77DA97D5+54]
```